# Ng-cli - Component Style Applied to Wrong Component Identifier

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a global style set with a type selector and wildcard:

```
div[class^="col-"] {
  ...
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have a component containing this HTML:

```
<div class="col-3">
  <h5>counts</h5>
</div>
```

My spec requires the `<h5>` be left aligned, not centered. So in my component's local css file i have:

```
h5 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

When i render the page, the header is centered. Trying to debug, i go to the Elements tab in Chrome Developer Tools and find the style in the document head (note the `ngcontent` identifier):

```
<style>h5[_ngcontent-c1] {
  text-align: left;
}</style>
```

But when i find the `<h5>` element in the same pane, i see (note the `ngcontent` identifier differs from the style identifier):

```
<h5 _ngcontent-c10>counts</h5>
```

So, i go back to the style in the document head and Edit as HTML the style to read:

```
<style>h5[_ngcontent-c10] {
  text-align: left;
}</style>
```

And my header element is left aligned, meaning the compiled source points the style at the wrong component identifier. Anyone experienced this? Is there a way to configure ng-cli to properly point my component style at the correct component identifier?

Angular: 5.0.2
ng-cli: 1.7.3
Typescript: 2.3.2

Comment: There must be something else coming into play, but I don't know what it is. Encapsulation is taken care of by the cli and we don't need to touch it. Could you try to post an example on stackblitz? I tried but it worked as expected...

Comment: Interestingly (or disturbingly, depending on your perspective) the problem disappeared after adding a second definition to the component's style sheet. Weird.